# Calculus of an imaginary electronic system

Tags: calculus, integration

An aspect of any electronic system is the relationship between the current, $I$, the charge, $Q$, and the time $t$. In a particular system these relationships are represented by:

$I=6e^{-t}Sin(2t)$ and $Q(0)=0$

As $I=\frac{dQ}{dt}$, find $Q(t)$ by using calculus methods.

In the given system, problems occur if the charge ($Q$) falls below $2.35$. Find a range of values of $t$ over which problems will arise. Provide a mathematical argument to support such response.

I understand how to find $Q(t)$ since it is the integral of $I(t)$, however, I do not understand the last part of the question. How to find a range of values that will cause such "problems". For example, what would be a problem in this? How would I find and evaluate such problems also?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're not being asked to find the problems. You're being told "problems" = "$Q<2.35$". Then you are asked "for what $t$ are there problems?", i.e., "for what $t$ is $Q(t)<2.35$?". You might as well have been told "my pencil turns to blue cheese when $Q(t)<2.35$" and asked "for what values of $t$ does my pencil turn to blue cheese?" But that doesn't mean you are being asked to evaluate the nature of blue cheese.

Comment: So in relation to your magical blue cheese phenomenon, I've been implicitly told that there WILL be problems for all values of t less than that of 2.35?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of the question asks you to find such ranges of values of $t$ that $Q(t) < 2.35$. That is, solve

$-\frac{6}{5}e^{-t}\left(Sin(2t)+2Cos(2t)\right)+\frac{12}{5} < 2.35$

for $t$. I suggest you use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) for that.

Comment: Do you think there could be other random values that may cause issues? Or would it be more of a uniform set of numbers? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You are interested in a set of values of $t$ that satisfy the inequality $Q(t) < 2.35$. From what I can tell, it'll be a set of two continuous ranges.

If you want, you can add your expression of $Q(t)$ into the question so that we could check it and localize your issues.

Comment: How would you simply add the expression of $Q(t)$ into the equation to localize issues?

Comment: @Brayden, have you obtained an expression for $Q(t)$? If you had, post it here so that we were clear on that. Next, solve an inequality $Q(t) < 2.35$ for the values of $t$. Is it clear?

Comment: The integral of $6e^{-t} Sin(2t)$ is $$-\frac{6}{5}e^{-t}\left(Sin(2t)+2Cos(2t)\right)$$

Comment: Which is the expression for $Q(t)$, however it's saying that there are problems when $Q(t) < 2.35$ not $t < 2.35$

Comment: @Brayden, first, you are missing an additive constant in your expression for the integral, and it is important in this problem. You have to find an additive constant so that $Q(0) = 0$. Is that clear? The next step will be solving the inequality $Q(t) < 2.35$ for $t$.

Comment: Fixed it, the equation is now: $$-\frac{6}{5}e^{-t}\left(Sin(2t)+2Cos(2t)\right)+\frac{12}{5}$$

Comment: I see now, ok i'll head to wolfram, thanks @svavil !